# How to generate documentation from XML documents?

Tags: xml, documentation, xsd, documentation-generation

I have been given a set of `XML` documents from a company that is meant to include the "documentation" of the `XML` schema. There are no `XSDs` provided.

How can I generate documentation (eg. `HTML` or `CHM`) from these XML documents that includes documentation as indicated below?

Here is an example of the XML content:

```
<ELEMENT1>

  <!--
  documentation text ....
  -->
  <ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>ABC</ELEMENT3>
  </ELEMENT3>

  <!--
  documentation text ....
  -->
  <ELEMENT4>
    <ELEMENT5>0534564117</ELEMENT5>
    <ELEMENT6>123456</ELEMENT6>
    <ELEMENT7>090314b4-fc7d-42c5-b382-a5b745671ee32b</ELEMENT7>
  </ELEMENT4>

</ELEMENT1>
```

Comment: How do you want the documentation generator to understand how documentation has to be parsed if the schema of the document is unkown?

Comment: I thought the above might be the standard way XML documents are documented so there would be a generator to create the documentation.

Comment: To your mind, how, in the given example, the HTML document should look like?

Comment: Something like: http://oxygenxml.com/samples/xml-schema-documentation/personal/personal.pdf

Comment: This is a documentation for XSD. It is possible to generate it because XML Schema has a specific element _xs:annotation_ used for documentation. Also, XSD files are normalized files and their rules are used by XSD documentation generator to produce their output.

Comment: So what you're saying is that it would be difficult to achieve this using the above pattern which I have been given?

Comment: So they've supplied the docs in the form of sample XML data with comments? That being the case you need an XSD, you can infer one from the XML data, then you can add annotations to the XSD (basically doing what they should have done in the first place). Once you have an annotated XSD there are several tools that will produce HTML documentation i,e. http://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/Office/2003/

Comment: How do you infer the XSD?

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem there may be a solution. But it will require some work:

1. Generate XSD from the XML files (with [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) for example -> [tutorial](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/05/28/generate-xsd-from-xml/))
2. Add the documentation to the produced XSD file (using `<xs:annotation/>` elements)
3. Generate documentation from the XSD (with [xs3p](http://xml.fiforms.org/xs3p/))

All the tools here are free. But if you can pay, [oXygen](http://oxygenxml.com/) seems to have very powerful features.

Comment: If I could automatically change all the `<!--` to `<xs:annotation` would that work?  Are they in the right place for it to work?

Comment: No, the comments are in your instance document, not in the schema. I would use a tool (such as oXygen) to generate a schema, then a custom XSLT transformation to extract the comments from your instance document and create annotation elements in your schema. It has to be a custom exercise because the "documentation" format you've got is non-standard.

Comment: If I extract the comments from the instance document, how could I automatically insert them in the right place in the generated XSD?

Comment: @CJ7 I'm sure, doing it by hand is the easiest way.